# Proxmox. ERROR: Backup of VM failed - CT is locked (backup)

Tags: debian, backup, virtual-machines, lxc, proxmox

I tried to create backup of the container (LXC) in my Proxmox and I get the error:

```
INFO: starting new backup job: vzdump 206 --node my_server --mode snapshot --storage backups-stor --remove 0 --compress lzo
INFO: Starting Backup of VM 206 (lxc)
INFO: status = running
ERROR: Backup of VM 206 failed - CT is locked (backup)
INFO: Backup job finished with errors
TASK ERROR: job errors
```

I many search the Internet and found the advices with command:

```
qm unlock <VM ID>
```

But when I execute this command on my server:

```
qm unlock 206
```

I got error message:

```
Configuration file 'nodes/myserver/qemu-server/206.conf' does not exist
```

How can I unblock my VM to create a backup?

Answer (score 10):

I solved my problem. **qm** manages the qemu VMs while **pct** is for containers (lxc). For unlock containers need to use command:

```
pct unlock <ID>
```

in my case:

```
pct unlock 206
```